# Is Quarkus production ready?

Tags: quarkus

We are building microservices using Java (Spring Boot) and while doing some research, found Quarkus as a solution to many of java in container world problems such as startup time and memory consumption. as such Quarkus is still 0.24.0, I am wondering when to consider using it in the Production environment. Or still consider as early adopter version?

Comment: Version numbers rarely equate to production readiness. Putty is at 0.73 and I would consider that *easily* production ready (quite stable, in fact).

Comment: There are already people using it in production who have shared there story (most privately). See https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users/topic/production.20usage for more

Comment: @Ronak just because I answered doesn't mean I am the one that downvited :) - which I didn't BTW. 


If the not having a answer comment was meant for me then I do have an answer and it's that for plenty of people running Quarkus in production it is production ready :).
Of course I understand the sentiment that it's new and moves fast so it could be considered something for early adopters at this stage. But that is more a testament to things being added and changed frequently and less about the produced applications' stability.

Comment: @geoand, I am sorry for confision. I did not mean to say that to you my friend.

Comment: @Ronak, no worries :)

Comment: If a 0.* version was the problem for considering it production-ready, wait no more: https://quarkus.io/blog/announcing-quarkus-1-0/

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on my experience with Quarkus.

Recently I've migrated one of my Spring Boot based microservices to Quarkus. The microservice becomes too 'fat' and was not sustainable for AWS t3.micro instance. 
Now is stable and with lower footprint. There is not a problem to fit in AWS t3.micro instance.

You can check this guide for more details about String2quarkus migration:
[Spring2quarkus — Spring Boot to Quarkus Migration](https://dzone.com/articles/spring2quarkus-spring-boot-to-quarkus-migration)

Comment: Great Work Triphon :)  Did you try with AdoptOpenJDK to compare the memory and CPU consumption of your Spring boot app? I guess they also claim a smaller cloud footprint. I have started to migrate one of my smallest microservice to quarkus but before I change the whole underneath technology stack, I would like to compare how do these 2 work and does it really make sense to migrate.

Comment: I am using [Amazon Corretto JDK](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/) - it is also open and the support for Java 8 is extended. I've did some tests - you can find them in the 'Some Application Performance Measurements' section in the article. Unfortunately the CPU monitoring chart was lost during the editing process, but you can check them also here in the [Original Variant in Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spring2quarkus-spring-boot-quarkus-migration-triphon-penakov/)
In General - CPU consumption is almost the same, but the memory and boot time - it is SIGNIFICANT improvement there.

Answer (score 0):

The stable release is scheduled to become available at the end of November 2019.

Check those links:

- https://quarkus.io/blog/announcing-quarkus-1-0/
- https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/red-hat-drives-future-java-cloud-native-container-first-quarkus?sc_cid=701f2000000tyBjAAI